# Can I pass a current variable through php? If so how?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm under a bit of a deadline so I was hoping that before I proceed down any paths someone could tell me if what I'm doing is feasable or if there is an easy/quick way to resolve it:

After running  into some issues with an accordion menu I have opted for an interim fix of using several menus and replacing each of them with js. I don't have the code in from of me but essentially:

```
function change-menu(menu){
var new-menu = menu + ".php";
(#menu-area).load(new-menu);
}
```

(I've only done a little work with js so far so please ignore the above syntax... I'll try to fix it later.)

And my link would be something like:

```
<a onclick="change-menu('something')">Something</a>
```

Inside the side menu are thumbnails for the artwork that will load in the window area and to keep it simple I'm just using a php include that will look something like:

```
<a href="art.php?id=picture1&name=blahblah">[img goes here]</a>
```

But I realized that when I do that I should also pass the menu to the next page as well so it knows what menu to initially load in the new page. But then I though - and I'm overanalyzing this and bit - if I want the experience to be stremalined and look a certain way even if I'm coding it a bit bitmakeshift at the moment I dont want someone to hit the back button and have the menu start opening and closing different parts.

So the question is:
Is there a way that I can tell the php link to import whatever the current state/value of the sidebar? I just want to make sure that the side menu only changes when the user clicks on it and not from hitting the back or forward buttons. Is this an easy action? Is it even a  possible action? Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into AJAX to achieve this. Using AJAX, you can get the new content as HTML from a php page and then use JavaScript to replace the existing content of the sidebar with the AJAX return. This way the content of the sidebar will be changed without reloading the page.

Comment: Thanks! I tried an AJAX function for the first time the other week in a similar solution an it worked great with the exception that the browser back button didn't work as I'd hoped afterwards (for instance if you click from pic 1 to pic 2 I want BACK to take you pack to pic 1 and not to the initial loading of the page) so that's why I thought php would be better until I realized my menu was doing to change with the back button. Could you elaborate on what you would recommend? I'm rather novice with most of this and learning as I go.

Comment: I don't think using back button for navigation is the best way to go. What you can do is store the previous URL somewhere(like session variable) and use this URL to redirect the user to the previous page. You can also use JavaScript's `window.history.back()` function or PHP's `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` to go back to the previous page but I won't recommend them because of their vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it in php. Use Javascript instead.

Comment: Great! and chance you can elaborate on that? 

The reason I was not staying exclusively with js was because I want the user to be able to go back and forth between items. For example, if they click on picture 1, picture 1 loads. If they then click picture 2, picture 2 loads. But I want them to be able to go back to picture 1 if they hit back